# Malformation in pom.xml file, by dependence

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube, pom.xml

I have a problem with pom.xml file, when i run my build now in jenkins, immediately i have this result:

> Error: Malformed POM C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\sonarqube-trigger-prueba\pom.xml: Unrecognised tag:'dependency'.
>
> line 23 column 14

I had incluyed the part of 'the dependence of JUNit 5', however i still have the same problem.

Please i need help with this.

thank you so much.

I have changed the pom.xml, but  i hadnt a different result, so..

Please i need help with this.
Thank you so very much.

---

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <dependencies>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>
        
       
        
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      
      <!--dependencia de JUNit5 -->
        
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>



    </dependencies>


        <build>
        
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                      <execution>
                      <id>post-unit-test</id>
                      <phase>test</phase>
                      <goals>
                      <goal>report</goal>
                      </goals>
                     </execution>
                 

                </executions>
                </plugin>
               </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

Comment: All the dependency should be isside dependencies tag only.

Comment: so should i  put the second dependency in the first one and then close everything in one?

Comment: Look into the structure of pom.xml in maven.

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the `<dependencies>` lines below, exactly above the first `<dependency>`. So the `<parent>` stays out of the `<dependencies>` section.

```xml
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>`

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>

    <!-- declare properties here -->
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

    <!-- add your dependencies here -->
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!-- additional dependecies here -->
        </dependencies>
```

Comment: <dependencies>
 
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <!--dependencia de JUNit5 -->
    
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>

</dependencies>

Comment: sorry for writing all together, i am new in this, but i still have the same error.Maybe it´s a directory problem.

Comment: You missed the answer. You need to move the tag `<dependencies>` from the line 5 of your pom.xml to the line ~15 of your pom.xml, just before the first occurrence of the tag `<dependency>`. To learn more about how to write properly a pom.xml file follow this link : https://www.javatpoint.com/maven-pom-xml